# Receiving datagrams using Udp connection

Tags: udpclient

In order to receive datagrams through an UDP connection I have created an object of type UDPClient.

```
 receivedNotificationSock = new UdpClient();
```

However once done and on using the receive method:

```
 receivedHostNameBuffer=receivedNotificationSock.Receive(ref receivedNotificationIP);
```

I am getting an exception saying that I must call the bind method.
But there is no bind method in the UDPClient class.
Could You guys please provide me with the code if possible as to what should be done to overcome this exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need I think to know some more about sockets.

All sockets possess a port number.  First, you create a socket - which is almost useless on its own.  It just floats there.  But then you bind it - you assign it a port number.  *Now* it's useful - now you can send and receive data on it.

Remember, all UDP communications are defined by the quad data set of the IP and port of the source and the IP and port of the destination.  A freshly created socket doesn't have an IP address or port; binding gives it an IP address and port.

Unfortunately, I'm not a C# programmer, so I can't properly answer your question.  But at least you know *why* it's important.

Comment: i am getting binding error while using udp connection... please help me as what can be done

Answer (score 1):

Pass the port number into the constructor of your UDP client.

```
 receivedNotificationSock = new UdpClient(21000);
```

You may need to change firewall settings to allow the bind, though a popup window normally opens when you first run this on your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

For Socket proramming you need to know the sequence of syscalls you need to do on client side and on the server side.

If you are writting a **client** :

1. you open a socket with a `socket` call.
2. you then connect to the server port with a `connect` call
3. once connect is successful
4. then you send the request to the server using either a `send` or `sendto`  or a `write`
5. which results in reception of data that you can read using a `receive` or `read`

**On Server Side**

1. you create a `socket`
2. `bind` it to a `port`
3. start listening on the socket for incoming connections from various clients using a `listen`. 
   There is a non blocking way of listening for connections as well with a `select` syscall.
4. Once the you establish a connection you can essentially read the request and start processing it.

Here's an example in C# that may be useful to you.

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/